# RecyclerView use so much memory until OOM

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-memory

"Memory" rose quickly after open the Fragment that contains RecyclerView.When scorll up and down several times，"memory" continue to rise,and then show OOM and Force Close.
[image]

The following is my Adapter code:

I just use one RecyclerView the full page and nested a GridView at the first item;

```
public class CategoryPagerItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {


//热门分类
public static final int VIEW_TYPE_HOT_SUB_CATE = 1;
//banner+商品横滑推荐
public static final int VIEW_TYPE_PROMOTION_LIST = 2;
public static final int VIEW_TYPE_PROMOTION_LIST_LABEL = 3;
//商品集合
public static final int VIEW_TYPE_GOODS_LIST = 4;
//商品集合标签
public static final int VIEW_TYPE_GOODS_LIST_LABEL = 5;
//加载更多
public static final int VIEW_TYPE_GOODS_LIST_MORE = 6;


public static final int COUNT_HOT_SUB_CATE=1;
public static final int COUNT_HOT_GOODS_LIST_LABEL=1;
public static final int COUNT_HOT_GOODS_LIST_MORE=1;

private String mTagId;//TabLayout的title对应的tagid
private String mTitleName;//TabLayout的title对应的name
private int mIndex = -1;//ViewPager的index
private int mLevel = 1;//级别分类

private Context mContext;

//相关的banner+横滑商品
private ArrayList<CategoryList.RelatedTagListEntity> mRelatedTagListEntityList;
//热门分类
private ArrayList<CategoryList.HotSubCategoryListEntity> mHotSubCategoryListEntityList;
//商品列表
private ArrayList<CategoryList.GoodListEntity> mGoodListEntityList;

private int mRelatedTagSize, mGoodsListSize;

private OnGoodsItemClickListener mOnGoodsItemClickListener;

public CategoryPagerItemAdapter(Context context, String tagId, String titleName, int index) {
    mTagId = tagId;
    mTitleName = titleName;
    mIndex = index;
    mContext = context;
}

public void resetData(ArrayList<CategoryList.HotSubCategoryListEntity> hotSubCategoryListEntityList,
                      ArrayList<CategoryList.RelatedTagListEntity> relatedTagListEntityList,
                      ArrayList<CategoryList.GoodListEntity> goodListEntityList, int level) {
    mHotSubCategoryListEntityList = hotSubCategoryListEntityList;
    mRelatedTagListEntityList = relatedTagListEntityList;
    mGoodListEntityList = goodListEntityList;
    mRelatedTagSize = mRelatedTagListEntityList == null ? 0 : mRelatedTagListEntityList.size();
    mGoodsListSize = mGoodListEntityList == null ? 0 : mGoodListEntityList.size();
    mLevel = level;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    //头部的十个分类
    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_HOT_SUB_CATE) {
        return new HotSubCateViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_classify_item_hot_sub_cate, parent, false));
    } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_PROMOTION_LIST) {//banner+商品横滑推荐
        return new PromotionViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_classify_item_related, parent, false));
    } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_GOODS_LIST) {//商品列表
        return new GoodListViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_classify_item_goods_list, parent, false));
    }  else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_GOODS_LIST_LABEL) {
        return new GoodListLabelViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_classify_item_goods_list_label, parent, false));
    } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_GOODS_LIST_MORE) {//更多
        return new MoreGoodsListViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_classify_item_more, parent, false));
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh, final int position) {

    switch (vh.getItemViewType()) {
        //热门分类
        case VIEW_TYPE_HOT_SUB_CATE:

            final HotSubCateViewHolder hotSubCateHolder = (HotSubCateViewHolder) vh;
            int horizontalSpacing = (UJiPin.SCREEN_WIDTH - UDensity.dip2px(mContext, 16) * 2 - UDensity.dip2px(mContext, 50) * 5) / 4;
            hotSubCateHolder.mGridview.setHorizontalSpacing(horizontalSpacing);
            hotSubCateHolder.mGridview.setVerticalSpacing(UDensity.dip2px(mContext, 20));
            final CategoryHotSubCateAdapter categoryHotSubCateAdapter = new CategoryHotSubCateAdapter(mContext, mHotSubCategoryListEntityList);
            hotSubCateHolder.mGridview.setAdapter(categoryHotSubCateAdapter);
            hotSubCateHolder.mGridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                    int hotSubViewType = categoryHotSubCateAdapter.getItemViewType(pos);
                    CategoryList.HotSubCategoryListEntity hotSubCategoryListEntity = mHotSubCategoryListEntityList.get(pos);

                    if (hotSubViewType == CategoryHotSubCateAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_HOT_SUB_CATE) {//热门分类
                        JumpUtils.JumpClassifyList((BaseActivity) mContext, hotSubCategoryListEntity.getLevel(), hotSubCategoryListEntity.getTag_id(), hotSubCategoryListEntity.getName());
                        UJPTrack.getInstance().setTrack((BaseActivity) mContext, UJPTrack.PAGE_CLASS_ + UString.urlEncode(hotSubCategoryListEntity.getName()),
                            "class-1-" + UString.urlEncode(hotSubCategoryListEntity.getName()));
                    } else if (hotSubViewType == CategoryHotSubCateAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_HOT_SUB_CATE_MORE) {//点击more
                        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, CategoryPagerMoreActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(CategoryPagerMoreActivity.EXTRA_STRING_CATEGORY_NAME, mTitleName);
                        intent.putExtra(CategoryPagerMoreActivity.EXTRA_INT_CATEGORY_INDEX, mIndex);
                        intent.putExtra(CategoryPagerMoreActivity.EXTRA_STRING_CATEGORY_TAG_ID, mTagId);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                        UJPTrack.getInstance().setTrack((BaseActivity) mContext,
                            UJPTrack.PAGE_CLASS_ + UString.urlEncode(mTitleName),
                            "class-1-more");
                    }
                }
            });

            break;
        case VIEW_TYPE_PROMOTION_LIST://banner+横滑
            PromotionViewHolder promotionViewHolder = (PromotionViewHolder) vh;
            final int promotionPosition = position - COUNT_HOT_SUB_CATE;

            //防止recyclerview复用出现错乱的办法是有if必须有else，并且处理相反
            GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams promotionLP = (GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) promotionViewHolder.mContainer.getLayoutParams();
            if (promotionPosition == 0) {//如果是第一个，则显示“相关推荐“
                promotionViewHolder.mLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                promotionLP.setMargins(-UDensity.dip2px(mContext, 5), UDensity.dip2px(mContext, 16), -UDensity.dip2px(mContext, 5), 0);
            } else {
                promotionViewHolder.mLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                promotionLP.setMargins(-UDensity.dip2px(mContext, 5), UDensity.dip2px(mContext, 4), -UDensity.dip2px(mContext, 5), 0);

            }
            promotionViewHolder.mContainer.setLayoutParams(promotionLP);

            final CategoryList.RelatedTagListEntity relatedTagListEntity = mRelatedTagListEntityList.get(promotionPosition);
            FrescoImageLoader.getInstance().load(promotionViewHolder.mCover, relatedTagListEntity.getCover());

            //点击banner
            promotionViewHolder.mCover.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    JumpUtils.JumpActivityTopic((BaseActivity) mContext, relatedTagListEntity.getName(),
                        relatedTagListEntity.getTag_id(), null, promotionPosition);
                    UJPTrack.getInstance().setTrack((BaseActivity) mContext, UJPTrack.PAGE_LABEL_ + UString.urlEncode(relatedTagListEntity.getName()),
                        "class-2-" + covertInt(promotionPosition + 1));
                }
            });
            final CategoryChoiceTagAdapter adapter = new CategoryChoiceTagAdapter(mContext);
            //点击横滑商品
            adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new CategoryChoiceTagAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTag4ItemClick(final CategoryList.GoodListEntity goodListEntity, int position, View view) {
                    Jumper.newJumper().putString(GoodsDetailActivity.EXTRA_STRING_GOODID, goodListEntity.getGoods_id() + "")
                        .putString(GoodsDetailActivity.EXTRA_STRING_SOURCENAME, "分类")
                        .putString(GoodsDetailActivity.EXTRA_STRING_SOURCEID, "活动横滑")
                        .jump((BaseActivity) mContext, GoodsDetailActivity.class);
                    UJPTrack.getInstance().setTrack((BaseActivity) mContext, UJPTrack.PAGE_GOOD + goodListEntity.getGoods_id(),
                        "class-2-" + covertInt(promotionPosition + 1));
                }
            });
            promotionViewHolder.mSlideMoreRecycleView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.setDataRefresh(relatedTagListEntity.getGoods_list());
            //横滑
            promotionViewHolder.mSlideMoreRecycleView.setOnSlideTwiceLisner(new SlideMoreRecycleView.SlideTwiceLisner() {
                @Override
                public void onSliding(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
                    JumpUtils.JumpActivityTopic((BaseActivity) mContext, relatedTagListEntity.getName(),
                        relatedTagListEntity.getTag_id(), "", promotionPosition);
                }
            });
            break;
        case VIEW_TYPE_GOODS_LIST_LABEL://商品列表的label
            break;
        case VIEW_TYPE_GOODS_LIST://商品列表
            int goodsListPosition = position - COUNT_HOT_SUB_CATE - mRelatedTagSize - COUNT_HOT_GOODS_LIST_LABEL;
            final CategoryList.GoodListEntity goodListEntity = mGoodListEntityList.get(goodsListPosition);
            final GoodListViewHolder goodsListHolder = (GoodListViewHolder) vh;

            ViewCompat.setTransitionName(goodsListHolder.ivCover, mContext.getString(R.string.transition_name) + position);
            goodsListHolder.rootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mOnGoodsItemClickListener != null) {
                        mOnGoodsItemClickListener.onItemClick(goodsListHolder.rootView, goodListEntity, position, goodListEntity.getThumbnail());
                    }
                }
            });
            goodsListHolder.tv_goods_selling_point.setText(goodListEntity.getSelling_point());
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(goodListEntity.getThumbnail()))
                FrescoImageLoader.getInstance().load(goodsListHolder.ivCover, goodListEntity.getThumbnail());
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(goodListEntity.getMark())) {
                goodsListHolder.ivGroupLogo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                FrescoImageLoader.getInstance().load(goodsListHolder.ivGroupLogo, goodListEntity.getMark());
            } else {
                goodsListHolder.ivGroupLogo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            goodsListHolder.tvDescription.setText(goodListEntity.getGoods_name());
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(goodListEntity.getGoods_price()))
                goodsListHolder.tvPrice.setText(String.format(mContext.getString(R.string.rmb), goodListEntity.getGoods_price()));
            //售罄
            if (goodListEntity.getProduct_stock_total() <= 0)
                goodsListHolder.ivSoldOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                goodsListHolder.ivSoldOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case VIEW_TYPE_GOODS_LIST_MORE://更多推荐
            MoreGoodsListViewHolder moreGoodsListViewHolder = (MoreGoodsListViewHolder) vh;
            moreGoodsListViewHolder.mContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    JumpUtils.JumpClassifyList((BaseActivity) mContext, mLevel, mTagId, mTitleName);
                    UJPTrack.getInstance().setTrack((BaseActivity) mContext, UJPTrack.PAGE_CLASS_ + UString.urlEncode(mTitleName), UJPTrack.PAGE_CLASS_CLASS + UString.urlEncode(mTitleName));
                }
            });
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onViewRecycled(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return VIEW_TYPE_HOT_SUB_CATE;
    } else if (position < COUNT_HOT_SUB_CATE + mRelatedTagSize) {
        return VIEW_TYPE_PROMOTION_LIST;
    } else if (position < COUNT_HOT_SUB_CATE + mRelatedTagSize + COUNT_HOT_GOODS_LIST_LABEL) {
        return VIEW_TYPE_GOODS_LIST_LABEL;
    } else if (position < COUNT_HOT_SUB_CATE + mRelatedTagSize + COUNT_HOT_GOODS_LIST_LABEL + mGoodsListSize) {
        return VIEW_TYPE_GOODS_LIST;
    } else {
        return VIEW_TYPE_GOODS_LIST_MORE;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mGoodsListSize + mRelatedTagSize + COUNT_HOT_SUB_CATE +
        COUNT_HOT_GOODS_LIST_LABEL + COUNT_HOT_GOODS_LIST_MORE;
}


//头部的热门分类
private static class HotSubCateViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private MyGridview mGridview;

    HotSubCateViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mGridview = (MyGridview) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    }
}


//banner+推荐横滑
private static class PromotionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private SimpleDraweeView mCover;
    private LinearLayout mContainer;
    private TextView mLabel;
    private SlideMoreRecycleView mSlideMoreRecycleView;

    PromotionViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mContainer = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll);
        mLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
        mCover = (SimpleDraweeView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_cover);
        mSlideMoreRecycleView = (SlideMoreRecycleView) view.findViewById(rv_tag_list);
    }
}

//商品列表
private static class GoodListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View rootView;
    SimpleDraweeView ivCover;
    TextView tvDescription;
    TextView tvPrice;
    TextView tv_goods_selling_point;
    ImageView ivSoldOut;
    SimpleDraweeView ivGroupLogo;

    GoodListViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        rootView = v;
        ivCover = (SimpleDraweeView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_cover);
        tvDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_descrption);
        tvPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_price);
        tv_goods_selling_point = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_goods_selling_point);
        ivSoldOut = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_sold_out);
        ivGroupLogo = (SimpleDraweeView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_group_tag);
    }
}

private static class GoodListLabelViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView mLabel;

    public GoodListLabelViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    }
}



private static class MoreGoodsListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private LinearLayout mContainer;

    MoreGoodsListViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mContainer = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);
    }
}

//点击双栏列表接口
public interface OnGoodsItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View rootView, CategoryList.GoodListEntity goodListEntity, int position, String imageUrl);
}

public void addOnGoodsItemClickListener(OnGoodsItemClickListener listener) {
    mOnGoodsItemClickListener = listener;
}

public String covertInt(int value) {
    return value <= 9 ? ("0" + value) : value + "";
}
```

Comment: you must be working with large size images. This leads to outOfMemory. For this you have to use small size images or use images in your project with different resolutions.

Comment: @AnkushBist I checked the images, most images is about 50k

Comment: Look image size and image dimensions are two different things. If your 50kb image has dimension of about 1000*1000 that means it is going to occupy about 1000*1000*4 or 1000*1000*4 space in memory. check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html#ARGB_8888

Comment: @AnkushBist Thanks bro,u saved me, the images dimension is about 1000x1000, i changed it to 375x375 now. it works

Comment: if you use use ARG_8888 this to display images this will decrease the chances of OOM to occur. But even after this OOM occurs but after fetching thousand of images.

Comment: @AnkushBist Thanks bro!